# Hyperledger fabric storing data on network againt such reference that does not exist

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have a scenario in which there is a participant "Bank" and Asset "AccountDetails". Problem is that without having a Bank record hyperledger is allowing me to update AccountDetails against such bank that does not exist. Instead of this behavior, it must show error but showing this weird behavior.

```
asset AccountDetails identified by accountNumber {
  o String accountNumber
  o String accountTitle
  --> Bank bankID
  o Double balance
}


participant Bank identified by id {
  o String id
  o String branchCode
  o String name
  o String country
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this question is best answered by the comments shown here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3065#issuecomment-354953014

Hyperledger Composer doesn't enforce relationships (or those since 'disconnected' out on the ledger) - to try and preserve integrity of relationships would be a near impossible task (CouchDB is a key/value DB, not a relational DB :-)